# Difference of two functions

Tags: java, recursion

I have one question regarding recursive functions and updating function parameters. Namely, I have two functions:

```
public static void populateArray(int[]level,Node root,int currentLevel) {

    currentLevel++;
    if(root.left!=null) {
        populateArray(level,root.left,currentLevel);
    }
    level[currentLevel]++;
    if(root.right!=null) {
        populateArray(level,root.right,currentLevel);
    }

}

public static void populateArray2(int[]level,Node root,int currentLevel) {

        if(root.left!=null) {
            currentLevel++;
            populateArray2(level,root.left,currentLevel);
        }
        level[currentLevel]++;
        if(root.right!=null) {
            currentLevel++;
            populateArray2(level,root.right,currentLevel);
        }

    }
```

These functions should fill an empty array with number of nodes in binary tree at each level. I thought that these functions work the same way, but it turns out that first function does that task correctly, and the second one doesn't, that is, `currentLevel` is not updated after returning from recursive call in the second function, and I am curious why is this the case?
I thought that in both functions, when we return from recursive call, parameter will be automatically updated (what is the case with the first function).
Second function will only work if after each recursive call we place `currentLevel--` .. Does someone maybe know why this happens? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This looks a lot like you should be passing `currentLevel + 1` to the recursive call, rather than incrementing the variable and then passing it.

Comment: Yes you are right, your method one works. It is a little bit weird logic flow how it is done, but when analyzing deeper it works. I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `populateArray2` you're first accessing the `level[currentLevel]++` and only then increase the `currentLevel` by 1 if the `root.right != null`.

I've added some comments to your code to highlight the difference:

```
public static void populateArray(int[]level,Node root,int currentLevel) {
    currentLevel++; // Increase currentLevel by 1 first
    if(root.left!=null) {
        populateArray(level,root.left,currentLevel);
    }
    level[currentLevel]++; // Increase level by 1 after that
    if(root.right!=null) {
        populateArray(level,root.right,currentLevel);
    }
}

public static void populateArray2(int[]level,Node root,int currentLevel) {
    if(root.left!=null) {
        currentLevel++;
        populateArray2(level,root.left,currentLevel);
    }
    level[currentLevel]++; // Increase level by 1 first
    if(root.right!=null) {
        currentLevel++; // Increase currentLevel by 1 after that
        populateArray2(level,root.right,currentLevel);
    }
}
```

So that's the key difference here, causing different results because different levels are increased.

In addition, if both the `root.left` and `root.right` aren't null, you've done `currentLevel++` twice in your `populateArray2` method as well.

I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish with `populateArray2`, but I would just remove it and stick with your original `populateArray`-method..

---

EDIT: As mentioned by *@Simon*, I've only addressed the difference between the two `populateArray` methods as was the question of OP. I haven't mentioned an actual fix for his requirements.

[See *@Simon*'s answer below for an actual fix following those requirements.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51855583/1682559)

Comment: yeah, i think i understood.. i didn't know why current level won't update, but i see that after returning from recursive call it won't update because it has been already incremented before recursion.. thanks!:)

Comment: @Simion You're indeed right! I've only highlighted the differences between the two methods which I saw as the primary question that was being asked, but I haven't provided an actual fix following OP's mentioned requirements. I've edited my answer with a link to your answer, which I've also upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Your second function doesn't work properly because you are incrementing twice if the Node has both LEFT and RIGHT elements .
Hence u need `currentElement--` at the end